# latex.exc.LatexBuildError: None for `latex.build_pdf()`

Tags: python-3.x, latex, archlinux

I try to run the following Python code on Arch Linux with `texlive-*` installed:

```
from latex import build_pdf

# Read the template from the file...
min_latex = (r"\documentclass{article}"
             r"\begin{document}"
             r"Hello, world!"
             r"\end{document}")

# Compile it...
pdf = build_pdf(min_latex)

# Save the generated .pdf to a new file...
path_to_save = 'new_file.pdf'
pdf.save_to(path_to_save)
```

It returns an exception: `latex.exc.LatexBuildError: None`

And I can't build neither any latex file, nor a string, nor using any of the builders.
I've tried to use `LatexMkBuilder()` (after installing `latex-mk` from AUR) and `PdfLatexBuilder` `.build_pdf()` manually, but no results.

However, it worked before (ca. a month ago). IDK what really happened.
Any suggestions?

---

Update 1: it starts to fall in `subprocess.check_call()` of `build_pdf()`.

Update 2: it seems like, in `latex`, creating a temporary file is a problem, and that cause `FileNotFoundError` for `subprocess.check_call()`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when running my script in PowerShell (but not in git-bash, for some reason). I found out that changing the builder from `latexmk` to `pdflatex` helped; i.e., in this example let:

```py
pdf = build_pdf(min_latex, builder='pdflatex')
```